# Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

Though there are similar questions and answer for my issue but nomn helped so i am posting here.

So I have env specific property file like -

```
application.properties
application-local.propereties
application-dev.propereties
application-test.propereties
application-stage.propereties
```

And then in my AppCpnfig class i have used

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

I am using intellij where in run configuration i have set local. 
My application is maven project.

In all the property files (except application.properties) i have also put following entries to set that specific env. For example -

```
 spring.profiles.active=local
 -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

But still getting this issue when i build my application -

However when i build this application it fails with the issue -
Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value

```
classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties
```

Please help in case anyone knows of a fix for this.

Comment: Can you try `#` instead of `$`?

Comment: Don't... Spring Boot already loads that for you, you are just working against the framework. Remove the `@PropertySource` and Spring Boot will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

you should not make entry with **-Dspring.profiles.active=local** in properties file instead pass it from outside while running the jar file for example:

java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=[yourProfileName] [jarFilePath].jar

Also you can overcome to the issue in case the file not found:

@PropertySource(value="classpath:missing.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)

Comment: He shouldn't be doing this in the first place. Spring Boot already takes care of all of this. Work with the framework not around/against it.

Comment: But she didn't mention she is using springboot and it's framework facility to handle missing file. In case of springboot she can directly use @Value and framework will automatically collect the property value based on the env and property file name. For example:  for dev environment application-dev.properties will be picked up.

Comment: It is in the list of tags.

Comment: can you please highlight as i can not identify.

Comment: Each question belongs to a group (aka tags) next to Spring , Spring Boot is one of those tags.

Comment: So the thing is , spring.profiles.active=local will get passed at runtime... but i get error on maven build itself

Comment: try to use directly @Value for reading the properties and remove the PropertySource that should work. Else please share few more details to further investigate the issue.